# Memory Leak using Seaborn / pyplot savefig

Tags: matplotlib, memory-leaks, seaborn

After googling for a day and reading a lot of suggested solutions I can´t shake a memory leak using pyplot.savefig with seaborn.
Code is inside a funcion that creates an image every few seconds:

```
puntos = df_graficos[df_graficos["ley"] == "CER"].reset_index(drop=True)
sns.set_style("ticks")
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=2, rc={"font.size":15,"axes.labelsize":20})
lm = sns.lmplot(x="dur", y="tir", data=puntos)
fig = lm.fig
r = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(r, format='png', bbox_inches="tight")
r = base64.b64encode(r.getvalue()).decode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")
lm.ax.cla()
```

Using memory profiler I detected that the memory used by  `fig.savefig(r, format='png', bbox_inches="tight")` is never returned. `lm.ax.cla()` returns the memory used by the seaborn object, but memory use keeps creeping up for every savefig. If I create the chart but don´t save it memory stays at the same level.

Tried everything from using threading to a combination of:

```
plt.close()
plt.close('all')
fig.clf()
lm.fig.clf()
```

As indicated before, the only thing that returns memory is `lm.ax.cla()`

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this really require seaborn?  Can you reproduce just with matplotlib and a self-contained example?  If so, please report to matplotlib.

Comment: Problem is detailed here https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/111 and here https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7270 
Solution is to call matplotlib.interactive(False)

Comment: Ah, so this is an ipython problem.  Good to mention what backend you are using when making reports about matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

According to [this experiment](https://qiita.com/Masahiro_T/items/bdd0482a8efd84cdd270), calling plt.close() before plt.clf() will not release the memory. You should call plt.clf() first before plt.close().